# JavaScript connection with HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, web-frontend

I am confused as to how I can use a single JavaScript File to connect to multiple HTML files.
I want to take the value given by the user in index.html, send that value to my JavaScript file and start the countdown based on what value the user has given. That countdown will be shown in work.html but after the start link is clicked, the page redirects to work.html, but no countdown comes up on the screen.
This is my index.html and javascript

```js
var remainingSeconds;

function workCountdown() {

  var countdownElement = document.getElementById("workcountdown");
  var work_minutes = document.getElementById("work_input").value;


  // Clear any previous countdown intervals
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  remainingSeconds = parseInt(work_minutes) * 60;
  countdownElement.innerText = formatTime(remainingSeconds);

  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    remainingSeconds--;

    if (remainingSeconds >= 0) {
      countdownElement.innerText = formatTime(remainingSeconds);
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      breakRedirect();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function breakRedirect() {
  location.href("break.html");
  breakCountdown();
}

function workRedirect() {
  location.href("work.html");
  workCountdown();
}

function breakCountdown() {
  var break_minutes = document.getElementById("break_input").value;
  var countdownElement = document.getElementById("breakcountdown");


  // Clear any previous countdown intervals
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  remainingSeconds = parseInt(break_minutes) * 60;
  countdownElement.innerText = formatTime(remainingSeconds);

  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    remainingSeconds--;

    if (remainingSeconds >= 0) {
      countdownElement.innerText = formatTime(remainingSeconds);
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      workRedirect();
    }
  }, 1000);
}


function formatTime(seconds) {
  var mins = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  var secs = seconds % 60;

  return padDigits(mins, 2) + ":" + padDigits(secs, 2);
}

function padDigits(number, digits) {
  return String(number).padStart(digits, "0");
}
```

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&family=Fredericka+the+Great&family=Lora:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&family=Monomaniac+One&family=Playfair:ital,wght@1,300&family=Poppins:wght@700&family=Raleway:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="background">
</div>

<h1 class="Welcome">
  Timer
</h1>

<form class="work">
  <h2 class="work_text">
    WORK:
  </h2>
  <input class="work_input" type="number" id="work" min="0" required>
  <br>
  <h2 class="break_text">
    BREAK:
  </h2>
  <input class="break_input" type="number" id="break" min="0" required>
  <br>
  <a href="work.html" onclick="workCountdown()" class="start_button">START</a>
</form>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

This is my work.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Work
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="workcountdown"> </div>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Originally I did it on the same page, where the countdown happened in index.html itself, and it worked, but I thought it might be cleaner and easier to keep it on different pages but because it is on different pages the countdown will not appear on the screen.

I'm really new to  web development so any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript loads completely fresh on each page. You need to use for example localStorage to save things across the pages

In this case, however, you just EITHER submit the form to work.html and get the passed values from the URL OR just hide the form:

There are several mistakes in your naming of things that I fixed too, for example `id="break"` but `getElementById("break_input")`

```js
let remainingSeconds;
const form = document.getElementById("workForm");
let countdownElement = document.getElementById("workcountdown");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the submit
  this.hidden = true; // hide the form
  workCountdown();
 
})

function workCountdown() {
  var work_minutes = document.getElementById("work").value;
  // Clear any previous countdown intervals
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  remainingSeconds = parseInt(work_minutes) * 60;
  countdownElement.innerText = formatTime(remainingSeconds);

  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    remainingSeconds--;

    if (remainingSeconds >= 0) {
      countdownElement.innerText = formatTime(remainingSeconds);
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      breakRedirect();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function breakRedirect() {
  breakCountdown();
}

function workRedirect() {
  //location.href("work.html"); // nextt line would never have been seen
  countdownElement = document.getElementById("workcountdown");
  workCountdown(); 
  
}

function breakCountdown() {
  var break_minutes = document.getElementById("break").value;
  countdownElement = document.getElementById("breakcountdown");


  // Clear any previous countdown intervals
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  remainingSeconds = parseInt(break_minutes) * 60;
  countdownElement.innerText = formatTime(remainingSeconds);

  var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    remainingSeconds--;

    if (remainingSeconds >= 0) {
      countdownElement.innerText = formatTime(remainingSeconds);
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      workRedirect();
    }
  }, 1000);
}


function formatTime(seconds) {
  var mins = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  var secs = seconds % 60;

  return padDigits(mins, 2) + ":" + padDigits(secs, 2);
}

function padDigits(number, digits) {
  return String(number).padStart(digits, "0");
}
```

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fjalla+One&family=Fredericka+the+Great&family=Lora:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&family=Monomaniac+One&family=Playfair:ital,wght@1,300&family=Poppins:wght@700&family=Raleway:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="background">
</div>

<h1 class="Welcome">
  Timer
</h1>

<form class="work" id="workForm">
  <h2 class="work_text">
    WORK:
  </h2>
  <input class="work_input" type="number" id="work" min="0" required>
  <br>
  <h2 class="break_text">
    BREAK:
  </h2>
  <input class="break_input" type="number" id="break" min="0" required>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="start_button">START</button>
</form>

<div id="workcountdown"> </div>
<div id="breakcountdown"> </div>


<script src="script.js"></script>
```